# SetcontentView after a video is played once

Tags: android, android-videoview

```
public void playvideo()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.testvideo);  

    VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);    
    String videoName = "testvideo" ;
    // You build the URI to your video here 
    StringBuilder uriPathBuilder = new StringBuilder (); 
    uriPathBuilder.append ("android.resource://"); 
    uriPathBuilder.append (this.getPackageName ()); 
    uriPathBuilder.append (File.separator); 
    uriPathBuilder.append ("raw"); 
    uriPathBuilder.append (File.separator); 
    uriPathBuilder.append (videoName); 
    Uri uri = Uri.parse (uriPathBuilder.toString ()); 

    video.setVideoURI (uri); 
    video.start ();    
}
```

This is the function for playing a testvideo. This function is call upon when a button is click. I want to call upon another function after the video has finish playing.

Answer (score 1):

You're maybe looking for [`setOnCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29).

```
video.setOnCompletionListener( new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
{
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
        {
            // call some function
        }  
});
```

Comment: Dear Sky, i went and try to understand setOnCompletionListener, however i do not really get this meaning. Sorry for being a noob. Coul you set an example on how to link to say start().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call another function then you can override

```
video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){});
```

whenever your video will finish it will call the above callback functiona and you can do whatever function you want.